# Does Simperium allow multi user collaboration?

Tags: collaboration, simperium

On their [Overview](https://simperium.com/overview/) page one of the bullet points under "What it does" is:

```
Multiple users can collaborate with the same data at the same time
```

However there's nothing in the documentation to suggest how this can be done, all the real time syncing is done only between devices logged in with the *same* user. Their own Simplenote app which is built on the platform *does* allow multi-user collaboration, but this would appear to be using a private API that is not available to normal Simperium clients.

Is there something I've missed? Is it a feature that will be added in the future? If so, when?

Answer (score 0):

We didn't release the collaboration feature yet, but if you'd like to test it, please, mail us and we'll get in touch with you: jorge.perez@automattic.com

Thank you!